# Calling fork seemingly jumps back to the beginning of the program

Tags: c, concurrency, fork

I noticed that in this code, `fork` makes the program go back to the beginning rather than sort of keeping on.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 10;
    printf("What??? ");
    int *b = &a;
    printf("%p\t", b);
    int tm = time(0);
    
    int f = fork();
    if (!f) *b = 15;
    else while(time(0) == tm);
    printf("%d %p\t", *b, b);
    
}
```

The output I expect is a single `What???`. The numbers are what I was initially trying to figure out, so I don't have an expectation related to that. However, I get two `What???`s. An example of the current behavior is `What??? 0x7fffd7120334  15 0x7fffd7120334       What??? 0x7fffd7120334  10 0x7fffd7120334`

To make the code clearer, what I was writing was initially related to if forcing a variable to be a register when using concurrency would change anything.

I tried taking the `fork` call out of the condition (which is currently out), and I also tried using a block if that would somehow change anything.

Comment: Calling `fork` does not make it go back to the beginning of the program.

Comment: You might want to add `\n` to your `printf` calls, and/or call `fflush(stdout);` right before calling `fork`.

Comment: Note that `fork` gives you a brand-new *process*, not a new thread.  So you're unlikely to see any concurrency issues when using `fork` in any case.

Comment: @SteveSummit `\n` made it work, `fflush` also did. I was going to ask why but an answer just gave the reason.

Comment: Not related to `fork` but `time(0)` returns a `time_t`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stream `stdout` is, by default, either line-buffered or fully buffered. Therefore, the line

```
printf("What??? ");
```

will likely put that string into the output buffer, without flushing it.

When you call `fork`, the output buffer is duplicated, so that when the output buffers of both processes are eventually flushed, that string is printed by both processes.

To prevent this from happening, you should flush the output buffer before the call to `fork`, for example by using the function call `fflush( stdout );`. If `stdout` is line-buffered (which is normally the case when connected to a terminal), inserting a newline character should also be sufficient.